# Open in app option to open the current page in native app

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, firefox-android

Firefox for Android has a very useful feature In the three dot menu called “Open in app”
[Open in app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YIPq.png)
It allows you to open the current page in the default application associated with that website. For example Reddit in the default app or Youtube in the default app.

How can I implement this feature on my website and Flutter App?

I couldn't find any sources on this

Comment: This is called deep linking (universal linking for Apple devices) and is supported natively by Flutter: https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/navigation/deep-linking

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.